# .NET Core changing the location where my default index.html file is

Tags: asp.net-core

I am building an Angular 2 app and using .NET Core and Webpack to compile my static resources into a dist folder.  I am using a plugin that builds my index.html file and puts it in my wwwroot/dist folder but am struggling on how to configure my Startup.cs file to look for the default file in the dist folder.

Currently I have...

```
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
```

In my startup.cs file but it will not use the index.html that is generated in my dist folder.  Any ideas on what I need to change?  The docs do not give much reference from what I could find on how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Does anything exist in wwwroot or just the dist folder?

Comment: @TravisBoatman I also have an images and icons folder.

Answer (score 9):

You can use code like below, but it only works when you put empty index.html in the root of **wwwroot** folder:

```
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        // Serve wwwroot/dist as a root 
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() 
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\dist"))
        });
```

RequestPath is empty by default so root path will show you index.html or default.html from wwwroot\dist folder.

**UPDATE**: There is easy and beautiful solution to handle this issue using **WebRoot** in `Program.cs` like below:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseWebRoot(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "dist"))
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

In `Configure` method of `Startup.cs` you just use:

```
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to change the directory for the static files, by passing StaticFileOptions to the UseStaticFiles method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files

Comment: This alone isn't enough in ASP.NET Core 3. While it will change the static files folder, SPA will still look in wwwroot.

Comment: You need to set different options for SPA
app.UseSpa is your friend to configure SPAs

Answer (score 0):

In net core 6 you have to configure it in WebApplication.CreateBuilder via WebApplicationOptions

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions { 
Args = args,
WebRootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "dist")});
```

That's it. Also there you can change ContentRootPath. Only this thing works for me. So, my empty core project Program.cs look like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions { 
    Args = args,
    WebRootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "dist")
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.Run();
```