# ASP.NET Core - serving static files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, static-files

I'm following this documentation but I'm getting stuck:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files

Consider my directory structure:

```
wwwroot
    dist
        index.html
```

In my startup class, I have:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "dist"))
    });
}
```

When I start the application I don't see my index.html page, but I do if I navigate to `<host>/dist/index.html`

How can I configure this so that ASP.NET automatically takes me to that page from `<host>`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll have create middleware or a URL rewrite to do the work for you. ASP.NET Core isn't the smartest and it isn't going to manually do stuff for you.

You should also be doing `WebHostBuillder.UseWebRoot(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "dist"))` in your `Program.cs` file.

Also, this looks like a duplicate of [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316230/net-core-changing-the-location-where-my-default-index-html-file-is)

Comment: Yes, he just need to change the WebRoot from wwwroot to wwwoot/dist. A new middleware isn't really needed