# Simplest standalone static file server for .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, webserver

I wrote the question on how to write a simple static file server for .NET Core using as few lines and files as possible.

It got marked as duplicate of [ASP.NET Core - serving static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552422/asp-net-core-serving-static-files). So my question is:

Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48554566/694331) really the *simplest* .NET Core static file webserver possible? Have I understood it correctly (I am trying to piece together information from all kinds of sources)?

*Startup.cs*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace StaticFileServer {
    public class Startup{

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app){
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() 
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\dist"))
            });
        }
    }
}
```

*Main.cs*

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace StaticFileServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple standalone static file server for .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635011/simple-standalone-static-file-server-for-net-core)

Comment: @vzwick If you read the question, the one you refer to as possible duplicate is my closed question that I refer to in *this* question.

Comment: I know. As a 35k rep user, you should also know that the way to do things is to edit your original question and request a reopening rather than creating another dupe.

Comment: @vzwick Experience tells me it it won't be reopened though, and my question remains unanswered. True that I should delete it, rather than create duplicates.

Comment: Why does the "as few lines as possible" matter? No reasonable amount of user code will be even a small fraction of the dependencies required. What you have is minimally sweet from an aspnetcore POV.

Comment: @spender Mainly pedagogical reasons. As it is used in an example, having a lot of extra code (the webserver part) that the user might be unfamiliar with, will make the example harder to grasp.

Comment: A relatively fully-fledged (extendable/pluggable) webserver in ~14 significant lines of code? It really doesn't get much better than this. You could always write a nuget package that reduces it down to a call with some parameters and publish it. Then you'd be able to do it in about 3 lines in a repeatable way. It all depends where you want to draw the boundaries of abstraction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Putting the codes together, the simplest complete application I have found for serving static files from that location is the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .Configure(config => config.UseStaticFiles())
            .UseWebRoot("wwwroot/dist").Build().Run();
    }
}
```

If you are trying to keep things light, you can include `Microsoft.AspNetCore`, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles`. Or for quick setups, you can just install the one package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`.

Comment: Thanks! That is quite simple indeed. In the end, I didn't use the default builder as you suggested, as it also logged info that I didn't want. My "final" example ended up like this: https://github.com/jirenius/csharp-res/blob/master/examples/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.cs

Comment: To get this to work I had to add a `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;`

Comment: If you want requests to default to eg. index.html when no file is specified, then add 'UseDefaultFiles' in front of 'UseStaticFiles'. Like this: `config.UseDefaultFiles().UseStaticFiles()`

Comment: I used your code in an empty console application, which worked after adding the following NuGet packages `Microsoft.AspNetCore` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles`

Answer (score 7):

### For .NET 6 / C# 10 or above

If it's simpler with [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements), [global using directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#global-using-directives) and [minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples):

1. Create a ASP.NET Core Empty project

   ```sh
   dotnet new web
   ```
2. Change (create if not exist) `Program.cs` to

   ```cs
   var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
   builder.Services.AddDirectoryBrowser();
   var app = builder.Build();
   app.UseFileServer(enableDirectoryBrowsing: true);
   app.Run();
   ```
3. Run it. You can change [host configuration values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host#host-configuration-values) like `urls` or `webroot` with [command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#command-line). For example:

   ```sh
   dotnet run -- webroot="C:/your-path/" urls="http://127.0.0.1:1234"
   ```

---

*Note:* To serve non-standard content type, 404 may be returned. You need to [add extra configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#non-standard-content-types) by:

```cs
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
{
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
    StaticFileOptions =
    {
        ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
        DefaultContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    }
});
```